# Write info about nodes to a CSV file on the controller (the local)

Tags: python, csv, logging, ansible

I have written an Ansible playbook that returns some information from various sources. One of the variables I am saving during a task is the number of records in a certain MySQL database table.

I can print out results in the playbook quite well.
What I want to do however is write the results from all hosts in a single (csv) file on the master/control server or computer running the playbook

```yaml
- name: Show results
  debug:
    msg: "URL: {{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_nodename']}} RECORDCOUNT: {{results.stdout}} BASE VERSION: {{baseversion.stdout}}"
```

This task prints the info I want for twenty nodes.
I now want to write this line in a single CSV file on the master server.

I've tried various things with local copy but until now to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shell` module can come up handy when no other solution visible:

```yaml
- name: Save results
  shell: echo URL: {{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_nodename']}} RECORDCOUNT: {{results.stdout}} BASE VERSION: {{baseversion.stdout}} >> /opt/my_file.log
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: thanks, didn't expect it to be this simple --- delegate_to: !

Comment: It is amazing. such big environment has to delegate writing output to old reliable shell...

Comment: @kakaz, since it's meant to run the same code against all machines, would you rather tell it to work remotely on every task that needs that, or run remotely by default and specifiy when to run locally?

Answer (score 0):

This method has issues if the content is too long where your echo error's out.
I ended up using the template module.

Just posting here as it may help someone else.